# Cannot Delete Repository Folder created by JGIT

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am unable to delete folder containing a cloned repository created using `jgit`. I have tried all kinds of utility delete methods but none works. The error thrown while using `FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file)` is as follows

`java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: \repositories\Test\Test\.git\objects\pack\pack-21cdd19e90e9e6bd2e8d295ea04201969594fe96.idx`

Tried the following,

1. I have seen a range of other answers, for example [1] and [2]. They are all concerned with cases wherein they created a repository with `jgit` first and then deleted it immediately after that. In my current scenario I want to check if a repository is already cloned at given path and delete if present. After doing this task, I want to clone a repository using `jgit` on the same path.
2. I tried cases wherein I created the repository with `jgit`, shut down my server. Started it again and then simply called a function to delete the folder created earlier. This again failed with the same error.
3. I also completely removed jgit from my initial code and from pom since it might be getting into loaded into classpath. I still get the same error when trying to delete. Tried again after restarting just to check, the issue still persists.
4. However, when I run the same deletion code from another Java program, it succeeds.

[1] [How to remove local repository by Java code that was cloned by JGit java library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124176/how-to-remove-local-repository-by-java-code-that-was-cloned-by-jgit-java-library)
[2] [How do I release file system locks after cloning repo via JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764311/how-do-i-release-file-system-locks-after-cloning-repo-via-jgit)

Here is the original code snippet for reference,

```
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(localRepositoryPath);

        // Delete directory if already present
        String localRepositoryParentPath = GitUtils.getRepositoryPath(projectName, null);
        File parentDirectory = new File(localRepositoryParentPath);
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(parentDirectory);

        // Create directory where repository will be cloned
        if(!file.mkdirs()) {
            throw new GitServiceException(
                GitUtils.getCloneFailureMessage("Unable to create directory",
                    projectName,
                    repoName));
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException | SecurityException | IOException e) {
        logger.info(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        logger.error("IO Error cloning repository {} and project {}. Stacktrace {} ",
            repoName,
            projectName,
            e.getStackTrace());
        throw new GitServiceException(
            GitUtils.getCloneFailureMessage("IO Error while cloning",
                projectName,
                repoName));
    }

    // Clone the git repository
    try (Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
            .setURI(repoUrl)
            .setDirectory(file)
            .setBranchesToClone(List.of("refs/heads/" + branchToClone))
            .setBranch("refs/heads/" + branchToClone)
            .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "token", this.credentials.getGitToken()))
            .call();
    ) {
        logger.info("Successfully cloned branch {} on path {} for repository {} and project {}",
            branchToClone,
            localRepositoryPath,
            repoName,
            projectName);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Error cloning repository {} and project {}. Stacktrace {} ",
            repoName,
            projectName,
            exception.getStackTrace());
        throw new GitServiceException(
            GitUtils.getCloneFailureMessage("Unable to clone repository locally",
                projectName,
                repoName));
    }
```

**Edit**

Adding error stacktrace

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOExceptionList: 1 exceptions: [java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: \repositories\Test\Test\.git]
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:345)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1206)
at com.adobe.mdloc.controller.TestController.post(TestController.java:57)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.adobe.asr.logging.http.servlet.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilter(AsrLoggingFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.adobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: \repositories\Test\Test\.git
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1425)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:338)
... 71 more

Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: \repositories\Test\Test\.git\objects\pack\pack-21cdd19e90e9e6bd2e8d295ea04201969594fe96.idx
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:110)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1180)
at org.apache.commons.io.file.DeletingPathVisitor.visitFile(DeletingPathVisitor.java:142)
at org.apache.commons.io.file.DeletingPathVisitor.visitFile(DeletingPathVisitor.java:36)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2724)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2796)
at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.visitFileTree(PathUtils.java:687)
at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.deleteDirectory(PathUtils.java:328)
at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.delete(PathUtils.java:303)
at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.delete(PathUtils.java:280)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1423)
... 72 more
```

Comment: Would need to see more of the exception to see what thee real cause is.... however, 2 things come to mind easy: permissions of the user that is running the process _and_ that the process be actually standing on that repo directory as its PWD.

Comment: To do a quick test, I just wrote a simple java program with the just the deletion code, It worked fine. Looking at the error I can make out it has access issues for the particular mentioned git file. What I cannot figure out is why specifically it does not work for this. I will do some more check, maybe am missing something obvious

Comment: Is it running on a windows box? If that's the case, _perhaps_ the file is open at the time (which is a **no-go** in windows, if the file is open).

Comment: What does `GitUtils.getRepositoryPath` do exactly? You certainly need to close the repo before deleting it, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266021/java-jgit-files-delete-fails-to-delete-a-file-but-file-delete-succeeds

Comment: I was using try with resource semantics as documented here https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java#L46. The function you are asking is just a utility to obtain the path where I want to clone the repo.

Comment: @eftshift0 the files were not open. I have been bitten by that mistake before so am careful about this. And yes, for better or worse, I am working on windows :)

Comment: Just in case, I don't mean the project files but the _repo_ files. I am assuming that you are closing the repo before trying to delete it.

Comment: As of now, I have just started from clone, which as you can see from the code I attached, that I check no previous repo was present, on that path before cloning. But if there was, I need to delete it. Currently I am not working on the repo files anywhere else that would lead to locking of files by jgit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Apache Commons IO function was throwing the error. Recursively traversing all files and deleting them using the `java.io` delete command worked perfectly fine.

Here is the code snippet used for reference,

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File file) {
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    if (children != null) {
        for (File child : children) {
            deleteDirectory(child);
        }
    }
    return file.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .close() method post Git clone and this will solve your issue.

```
try (Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(repoUrl)
        .setDirectory(file)
        .setBranchesToClone(List.of("refs/heads/" + branchToClone))
        .setBranch("refs/heads/" + branchToClone)
        .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "token", this.credentials.getGitToken()))
        .call()
        .close();
```